# Elasticsearch rejecting document upload as attempt to create a new mapping type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am attempting to create a new Elasticsearch document, in an index called uploads, with an automatically generated document ID. I am doing that by POST-ing the new document to `/uploads/_doc/`. Elasticsearch however is rejecting the upload, because it returns an HTTP response with a status of 400 Bad Request.

Elasticsearch thinks I am attempting to create a new mapping type, because the error message in the body of the response is

> Rejecting mapping update to [uploads] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, uploads]

**I am not trying to create a new mapping type**. I know that [each index may now hold only one mapping type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html).

I am using Elasticsearch 6.4.2 on Debian. I am using libcurl to send the HTTP request and receive the HTTP response.

Why is Elasticsearch interpreting my request as an attempt to add a mapping type? How do I change what I am doing to instead create a new document.

---

Using `curl` shows that the index currently has one mapping type, called `uploads`:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/uploads?pretty
{
  "uploads" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "uploads" : {
        "properties" : {
        ...
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        ...
        "provided_name" : "uploads"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add the index info, doing a GET /uploads and also an example of how you are trying to send the data in the POST?

Comment: Could you please provide the output of GET _cat/templates? Which is the name of your index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are POST-ing to the wrong URL. The URL must give the index name and the document type, rather than using `_doc`.

According your mapping your `uploads` index has an `uploads` document type:

```
{
  "uploads" : {                   <--- index name
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "uploads" : {              <-----doc_type name
        "properties" : {
        ...
        }
      }
    }
```

So you should use this document type and not `_doc`. That is, POST to `/uploads/uploads`, not to `/uploads/_doc`.